# Is there a way to delay video?

Tags: audio, video, hdmi

I bought a harman kardon speaker and I uses hdmi projector. Everything is awesome.

I can even play game. However, if I watch movie there is a delay on sound.

Which is strange. I don't see that sound latency when playing video games.

Basically I think I am just going to patch this up. Is there a way in media player to delay video?

That way the sound and video match?

Is there a way to measure precisely the sound latency?

Comment: which OS and media player do you use?

Comment: Use an audio codec like AC3Filter, which has a time shifter (i.e. play the audio earlier).

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to adjust the audio sync timing for playing videos locally on the windows system. Using media player classic.

[image]

VLC also has options to change the AV sync timing.
[image]
Picture from http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/03/fix-audio-syncing-problems-when-playing-videos/  which has an article for doing that for the OSX platform

It is odd that the gaming would be correct, and timing on that can be way more critical. I would first want to check whatever you were originally playing out of and discover if there already was a change made that is no longer necessary for your present setup.

HDMI can have its own issues that can be a minor amount that many people would not notice. As the data arrives at the HDMI tv device there can be a lot of buffering and delay for the whole signal, then the display processing engine can add also add up to 2 frames of delay. The audio in these devices is set to delay the same way as the video.
When instead the audio comes from your normal sound card, analog convert or data out and the video instead is following another path, with a completely different set of delays. Or also a USB audio device , with the usual USB buffering and digital conversions happening there.
Because of that sometimes it might be best to get your audio out of the HDMI tv output not direct from the computer, as at least one delay in processing the HDMI data is already accounted for.

With Audio software you have layers of possibilities for audio delay. Speaker fill can cause it, room correction can both cause it and slightly correct for delay between speakers. Any "enhancements" turned on can effect the delay.  Even any pre-processing could end up adding a few milliseconds over just passing it straight through.

[image]
Really oddly in this picture of room correction, you see my speakers are set at maximum distance and then corrected from there. My speakers are only 2 feet away :-)  but the method they use is to add delay, delay I was avoiding. Because speakers at a further distance would have the least delay, it is all crazied up to achieve the desired end results.

At any rate, offsetting things here and there, and not solving the actual problem IMO is just going to have audio syncs all over the place, and really that is way more common then it should be.

A "clap board" would be used in a video to be able to sync the video to the audio. A video could be made with you clapping your hands, dropping something or talking or about anything to compare if the audio matches the video. There are online downloadable videos with clapboard , that are probably within a frame or so.

In most cases of bad audio sync, happening everywhere, adding more delays to the delays , is a poor solution.  Bad lip-sync in movies (I find) is hard to determine which direction it would take to correct it. It is likely that the problem your seeing is because of delays that are already there, that you might be able to reduce.

Not enough information was supplied in the original question, so there are some things to think about for the subject general.

Comment: delay does happen in games too. I was wrong.